# Live development environment in windows when project is on Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, development-environment

Maybe this question is not so proffesional, but still, maybe someone has got into this issue as well. I am using windows os. And the project i am working on is on Linux servers. I am using Netbeans IDE and WAMP. The problem i ran into is that i cannot make the development environment configured via ALIAS or something similar. I want to DEBUG and run tests but the folder structure is different and it gives me errors, like in windows it is C:/wamp and on the Linux server it is /var/www . How can i make windows machine to get to understand the different file structure ? Maybe there are some guides ? I do not want to switch to Linux. I have everything configured and the only thing i need is like redirect from c:/wamp/myProject to /var/www/myProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that might not be possible.

You are trying to get one OS to read data from another OS

This is not a problem. However, your issue is that your files are located in directories of different structures, and you are trying to get Windows to read from **/var/www** directly.

Am I right?

Comment: Hi @phpnewbie2015 . The project is stored in bitbucket. I have cloned it from there, but all the includes are with /var/www so i need some kind of redirect so windows wont give me error.

Comment: Sorry, Pandemum. But, it cant work that way.  Or, rather it could work this way :  modify your .HTACCESS file, to redirect all files with "/var/www"..........to  "C:/wamp".   The problem with this is :  you would need to create a separate rule for EACH file.